# Calling Web Service with Querystring

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I want to auto-fill the **first** and **last** name fields if my user has an **email** already existing in the database. There is a web service that returns the user's information using the following querystring: `http://localhost:5555/Person/Search?text=user@email.com` so would like to tap into this service and utilize it.

I'm trying to write a method that will create a query string and see if that **email** exists in the database. If that **email** exists, then assign the **first** and **last** name values to the appropriate text-box fields.

**Current Method -- I know this method is incorrect, but this is what I've got**

```
public class Person : Page
{
    public void GetPersonInformation(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      string queryString = Request.QueryString["text"];
      if (queryString != null)
      {
          // What should I put here...
      }
    }
}
```

> **Question:**
>   How can I get this method to check the database for the email? Another concern is how to assign the **First** and **Last** name values to the appropriate fields if the **email** does exist.

**Current Form**

**Additional Info**
Assume that a user types an email that already exists. Once that user presses tab, it will auto-fill the **first** and **last** name fields if that **email** exists in the database. 
[image]

**Resource Used:** http://www.dotnetperls.com/querystring

Comment: I thought this would be enough information because my querystring is pulling the data that I want to store and use to auto-populate my first and last name fields.

Comment: I interpreted this as 'how do I make a webservice call and then use the response to fill the page', is that what you're asking?

Comment: Are you saying that the service at `http://localhost:5555/Person/Search?text=user@email.com` returns the information from the database for you, you just don't know how to talk to the service?

Comment: Sorry @mason... Let me clarify. DrewJordan is correct. The service is pulling the correct data, but I don't know how to store/capture that data returned from the service and manipulate it. Does that make sense?

Comment: Is that service part of your own site, or is it a separate site?

Comment: If the service returns the email field as null, then it doesn't auto fill, but if the service has as matching email, then it should auto-fill the email field

Comment: The service is something from my own website

Comment: Okay. Rather than calling the service over HTTP, you may be able to directly call its methods depending on how it's hosted. Look through your site and find the code responsible for the service. It might help by looking for a folder called Person or class call Person. Check your routing as well (often configured in global.asax.cs) to help you find it. Once you find the code responsible for the service, edit it into your question.

Comment: There are tons of different ways to make queries to a database. What database are you using? Are you using any frameworks to talk to it? We need this information before we can give you a concrete answer.